# LPLinkView backgroundColor not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, uikit

I am using LPLinkView from LinkPresentation module to present rich links in my app. But when I try to change the background color for the LPLinkView it's rendered as below.

[image]

When I tried changing the backgroundColor of the subviews of the LPLinkView, there is no element in the array returned from UIView's subviews property. Here is what I tried

```
let linkView = LPLinkView(metadata: metadata)
linkView.backgroundColor = .red
linkView.subviews.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = .red}
```

Comment: Were you able to get any leads on this?

Comment: @SameerNawaz we can't change the color of the view. Instead, we can switch the interface style, so that it will be subtle in the UI.

Comment: Yes I found a work around

Answer (score 0):

We can't change the design, but we can get the contents from it and create our own view.

```
import SwiftUI
import LinkPresentation

struct LinkModel { let image: Image, title: String?, linkHost: String?, link: URL? }

class LinksDataModel: ObservableObject {
    
    static func fetchMetadata(for url: URL, completion: @escaping (LinkModel?) -> Void) {
        let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
        metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { (metadata, error) in
            if let metadata = metadata {
                // load image
                metadata.imageProvider?.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self, completionHandler: { image, err in
                    if let uiImage: UIImage = image as? UIImage {
                        let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                        completion(LinkModel(image: image, title: metadata.title,
                                             linkHost: metadata.url?.host, link: metadata.url))
                    } else { completion(nil) }
                })
            } else { completion(nil) }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call the function onAppear

```
@State private var linkModel: LinkModel? = nil

if let model = linkModel {
    LinkView(model: model)
}

.onAppear {
    LinksDataModel.fetchMetadata(for: url) { linkModel in
        if let model = linkModel {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.linkModel = model }
        }
    }
}
```